# Counting up the value and performing calculation using LCD Arduino

Tags: while-loop, arduino

I am new to Arduino programming. My condition is I want to count up a value of i from 0 using while loop. At the same time, a calculation, b is needed to be performed continuously when counting up the value. However, the counting start from 90 instead of start from 0 when the calculation b is performing. Can anyone can help me on it? Thanks.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(20, 4);
}

void loop() {

  int i;

  while (i>=0){
    i++;
    lcd.setCursor(1,1);
    lcd.print("b");
    lcd.setCursor(3,1);
    lcd.print(i);
    delay(1000);

  int c;

    c = i + 2;
    lcd.setCursor(1,2);
    lcd.print(c);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code should not even compile as `b` is not declared.

You initialize i with 0. So `while (i>0)` is never the case.

If you fix both you end up in an infinite loop. Not sure if you want that as there is some code after the while loop.

So pick a limit for i and use that in a for loop.

If you want to use a while loop make sure your loop condition is true `>=0`

You also might want to add a delay as otherwise your values change way too fast for you to see.

Comment: Hi @piglet, how can I add the delay to the code? Since the delay added in the code cannot display the number slower.

Comment: @LAI I don't know what you mean with  "delay added in the code cannot display the number slower"

Comment: Hi @Piglet , I am done with the counting up part. However, how to do for the calculation part? Thanks.

Comment: @LAI ask a new question

Comment: Hi @Piglet, I have edited the question. Please help me thanks.

Comment: @LAI you're not supposed to change your question as it turns my answer useless... you have to initialize i with a value, otherwise you use some garbage from that memory location. int i = 0;

Comment: How can I initialize the value i again since the initialization of i is in the code? Thanks

Comment: @LAI you only declared it. `int i;` does not assign a value to `i` you need `int i = 0;` if you want to start with i being 0. otherwise you get whatever garbage is at that memory location if you use i.